# Binary in GraphQL

Tags: binary, graphql

According to the [docs about scalars](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#scalar-types) in GraphQL there is no support for binary data up to now.

According to above page it is possible to define own Types.

How could you implement a binary scalar in GraphQL?

Comment: Does your GraphQL endpoint respond with JSON, or something like BSON that could encode binary data efficiently?

Answer (score 4):

I came here looking for an answer and after some reflection I got to the following conclusion, it is not a direct answer to the question but I think it is related and important to consider. You shouldn't implement a binary scalar in GraphQL.

I think for small images the encode as base64 solution will work great but for bigger files it goes against the design philosophy of GraphQL about efficient data transfer, so a better alternative would be to have those files somewhere else, like a CDN and just use the reference in GraphQL.

Size matters, for small queries it could make no difference but for big complex queries it could be a big performance problem.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation seems to hint that custom types would still somehow boil down to default types:

> In most GraphQL service implementations, there is also a way to specify custom scalar types. For example, we could define a Date type.
>
> Then it's up to our implementation to define how that type should be serialized, deserialized, and validated. For example, you could specify that the Date type should always be **serialized into an integer timestamp**, and your client should know to expect that format for any date fields

The first thing that pops to mind in this case will be a [base64-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) string. Depending on your language of choice [SO likely will have](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=base64) a sample serialisation/deserialisation routines.

Answer (score 1):

You can but have to use default data-type to create a new one. For audio, video or images you can easily convert it into base64 and pass them as a string but in that, you have to keep in mind the length of the data as it's not stored in the buffer.