# Using Uint8Array as an Argument for mutation in typegraphql

Tags: javascript, typescript, graphql, typegraphql

I need to save a public key to my postgres database from graphql. Using a `Uint8Array` seems the best option to save this with (let me know if you have a better suggestion). Therefore I have the entity:

```
@ObjectType()
@Entity()
export class Wallet extends BaseEntity {
  @Field()
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id!: number;

  @Field()
  @Column({ type: 'bytea' })
  public_key!: Uint8Array;
}
```

And the resolver:

```
  @Mutation(() => User)
  async createUser(

    @Arg("email") email: string,
    @Arg("wallets", _type => [Uint8Array], { nullable: true }) wallets: Uint8Array[],
    @Ctx() { em }: MyContext
  ): Promise<User> {
    // input validation

    const user = {
      email: email,
      wallets: (wallets ? wallets.map(e => ({ 'public_key': e })) : [])
    }
    return { user: await em.save(User, user) };
  }
```

`CannotDetermineGraphQLTypeError: Cannot determine GraphQL input type for argument named 'wallets' of 'createUser' of 'UserResolver' class. Is the value, that is used as its TS type or explicit type, decorated with a proper decorator or is it a proper input value?`

I'm not sure I understand this error properly, can I not use Uint8Array as an input to my mutation or am I doing it incorrectly?

Comment: Looks like you need to create a [custom scalar type](https://typegraphql.com/docs/scalars.html#custom-scalars) first and then use that. `Uint8Array` is not a builtin scalar.

Answer (score 1):

GraphQL does not support binary types out of the box. It is recommended to use Base-64 encoded strings instead, which works well for small payloads. Read more: [Binary in GraphQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59213498/binary-in-graphql)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).